# Prove or disprove if $A^2$ = $B^2$, then $A$ and $B$ have the same eigen-vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was thinking that this question would be a prove as I was unable to find any counter-examples in the form of 2x2 diagonal matrices or 2x2 matrices with elements on the opposite diagonal.

My idea of proving would be to prove by contradiction that if v was an eigenvector for A i.e Av=$\lambda$v then assuming that v isn't an eigenvector for B we get that Bv=x and Bx= $\lambda^2$v since $A^2$v=$B^2$v=$\lambda^2$v then we somehow get the contradiction that x must be equal to $\lambda$v (Not sure how to do that bit exactly)

Am I on the right path or is there an easier/different way to go about this?

Comment: What if $A^2=B^2=I$?

Comment: Or even $B = 0$ but $A \neq 0$. Then $B$ has every vector(except the zero vector) as an eigenvector, but $A$ does not. You can construct $A$ so that  $A \neq 0$ but $A^2 = 0$ easily, use a (strictly) upper triangular $2\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: In the case that $B$=$0$ but A$\neq$$0$ that would make it a disprove. Thank you very much for that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $$A=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\ 0&-2\end{pmatrix}, \quad B=\begin{pmatrix}0&4\\1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$
Eigenvectors of $A$ are precisely the non-zero multiples of$\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ or of $\begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\end{pmatrix}$, and eigenvectors of $B$ are precisely the non-zero multiples of  $\begin{pmatrix} 2\\1\end{pmatrix}$ or of $\begin{pmatrix} -2\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

Thus, (assuming characteristic $\ne 2$) $A$ and $B$ do not have a single eigenvector in common.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $A=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$ and $B=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$

Comment: While correct, these still have at least *some* eigenvectors in common

Comment: Yes, @HagenvonEitzen, but not *the same* eigenvectors